# Why java is converting number to negative before change of radix

Tags: java, algorithm, math, numbers, number-formatting

In Java `String Integer::toString(long i, int radix)` returns representation of number `i` using given radix(base). Before it does conversion it is mapping number `i` to `-i`:

```java
byte[] buf = new byte[65];
int charPos = 64;
boolean negative = (i < 0);

if (!negative) {
    i = -i;
}

while (i <= -radix) {
    buf[charPos--] = (byte)Integer.digits[(int)(-(i % radix))];
    i = i / radix;
}
buf[charPos] = (byte)Integer.digits[(int)(-i)];
```

I do not understand why it works with negative number instead of positive. In Java `x % y = -((-x) % y)` so it is confusing to me because it should not do any difference because result of modulo operation is negated in the code.

Comment: Is this the source of `Integer.toString` or of `Long.toString`?

Comment: "In Java x % y = (-x) % y" are you sure? https://ideone.com/1eOX4R

Comment: `7 % 10` is something very different than `-7 % 10` (which is congruent to `3 % 10`).

Comment: @luk2302 are you sure? `-7 % 10 == -(7 % 10)`, as shown by to https://ideone.com/WqQrlU.

Comment: @luk2302 What does `3 % 10` have to do with `-7 % 10`. If you divide `-7` by `10`, you get `0`, with a remainder of `-7`. None of that has anything to do with the number `3`.

Comment: @Trismegistos yep, that's what I wrote, not what you wrote in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to add minus sign to modulo rule. I have corrected it now.

Comment: @luk2302 this time try Java :) The `%` operator doesn't mean the same in all languages, for example `-7 % 10` is `-7` in Java, but [`3` in Python](https://ideone.com/cutYKb).

Comment: @luk2302 Wolfram Alpha is not Java.

Comment: @luk2302 you're missing the point by continuing to assert that `-7 % 10 == 3` in Java.

Comment: What did you mean by "congruent to `3 % 10`" then? You introduced "mod", which is not what Java's `%` means: it's the [*remainder* operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3), not the mod operator.

Comment: This is why I'm always pedantic when people talk about the `%` operator and calls it the **modulus** operator. In Java, the `%` operator is the **remainder** operator, so says the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), section [15.17.3. Remainder Operator `%`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3).

Comment: @luk2302 since you say `-7 % 10 ≡ 3 % 10`, that means `-7 ≡ 3` in Java. What then does `≡` mean?

Comment: @AndyTurner For definition of congruent, see e.g. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html. The full phrasing would be that "-7 and 3 are congruent modulo 10", which is true, because both `-7 mod 10` and `3 mod 10` calculates to `3`. Of course, it's a *meaningless point* to make here, given that Java's `%` operator is not a *modulus* operator, but a *remainder* operator, and that `-7 rem 10 = -7` while `3 rem 10 = 3`.

Comment: @Andreas yes: it's the "what's the relevance *here*" that I was trying to establish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code doesn't want to handle positive and negative values differently, so it wants to unify the sign.

The most obvious normalization would be to convert negative value to positive. That's what we humans would do. But, with numbers stored in two's compliment, the *value range* of negative numbers it one larger than the value range of positive numbers, so if we normalized to positive, it would fail for `-2147483648`, aka `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: That's impressive. How did you know it?

Comment: @Trismegistos I just considered the question: What's special about negative values in an `int`. When you've handled fringe cases before, the fact that `-2147483648` doesn't have a positive counterpart become obvious.